# How to get STDOUT from termial to a file

Tags: javascript

I want to get this measurement out of the terminal to a file and only the STDOut I don't want a STDerr. Can you help me with this?

```
printf("Average measurement = %8.3f %s .\n", averageCalbMeasurement, units);
```

So here is the point i need help with. I just want it out as a normal file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the only line (and not all of stdout) you can use:

writeFile (example from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-program-to-write-data-in-a-text-file/ )

```
<script> 
// Requiring fs module in which 
// writeFile function is defined. 
const fs = require('fs') 
  
// Data which will write in a file. 
let data = "Learning how to write in a file."
  
// Write data in 'Output.txt' . 
fs.writeFile('Output.txt', data, (err) => { 
      
    // In case of a error throw err. 
    if (err) throw err; 
}) 
</script>
```